# Profile reputation has been reset

Tags: support, bug, reputation, badges

I added my gmail to [my profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/38952/pasan-eeriyagama) and it ended up resetting my rep points as below.

[image]

Looks weird above. I suddenly get old notifications saying you earned this badge, that badge. But no change in reputation points.  I had 650+ points before this happened. Appreciate help on this. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your salesforce.SE account got reset. Are all the other accounts rep correct?

Comment: Hi @Suraj Rao, Thanks. This is the most used account (haven't noticed in others though), I believe SF SE is the one with issue.

Comment: I can only guess.. but perhaps your gmail account may have been tied to another (unused) Salesforce.SE account which may have got merged... If all your accounts are affected, this might belong in MSE or if not it might belong in Salesforce.SE meta site..

Comment: Yes I had a previous account linked to newly added gmail, but I deleted that account completely before I add it as a login. not sure how it did over-write my working account? seems like a bug to me. Any thoughts how to fix this please. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to wait for an SO dev to check your post and fix it.

Comment: This may be the result of caching, or that something didn't align properly. I would suggest, in addition to this post, also using the contact us form to try to get your account fixed.

Comment: It looks like it's fixed for your salesforce account. This definitely looks like the result of an account merge.

Comment: Many Thanks guys, seems profile is back to normal.
Cheers!
Pasan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, there is something going wrong in the merge process, and it's been cropping up here and there for random profiles for the past couple weeks - someone's looking into it.

The problem itself doesn't seem to be causing any incredible harm to the users it affects, and you should be able to use the site normally. It is transferring all the posts and comments just fine, but it's not deleting the old profile it moved content from, and it's not running a reputation recalc on the destination profile to readjust you to your actual reputation.

But of those problems are easily solvable if you just make us aware, and you can even fix the reputation problem yourself. Just go to any of your posts, delete it, and undelete it again. This will schedule you for a reputation recalc, and it will occur within 30 minutes (whenever the system runs the cycle to process recalcs again).